# how to create a new lifecycle for develop maven plugin 2

Tags: maven, mojo, exec-maven-plugin

i am a maven newer

i use maven-mojo create a new maven-plugin project;

for example:

3 java file: mojo1.java,mojo2.java,mojo3.java

```
mojo1.java with @Mojo(name="test01")
mojo2.java with @Mojo(name="test02")
mojo3.java with @Mojo(name="test03")
```

how can i do or configure, it can execute one command ,

just like :mvn lifecycle-command ,

it can execute 3 commands in sequence: test01 test02 test03

thanks

Comment: No knowledge about maven but you want to create a maven-plugin? What is the purpose of that? What would you like to achieve?

Comment: hi,@khmarbaise ,thank you for your question. My team has written an automated testing framework, we want to use the goal approach to the Maven project, the direct implementation of the goal command to generate some data。But we find that goal and goal are in order, so we try to  deal with the life cycle.

Comment: Sounds weird why not using the surefire plugin which can run tests..or maven-failsafe if you like to run integration tests...Why invented a testing framework? Are the available ones not enough? What is so special?